# libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump, postgresql-12, libpq

I am trying to take a backup programmatically using pg_dump. I have copied all pg utilities under bin directory of /usr/pgsql-12/. I have also copied the library from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu to /usr/pgsql-12/lib and added /usr/pgsql-12/lib to PATH environment variable.
But still I am getting below error:

```
"Absolute path of postgres utilities: /usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_dump"

"Executing command : /usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_dump --blobs --format directory --host abc --lock-wait-timeout 300000 --verbose -U abc -d acme -f /backup/2023-06-23T06_23_57_657_0700/acme/abc/acme_pg_dump.dmp -p 5432 PGSSLMODE=require"

**"Error executing command: exit status 127, Out: /usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_dump: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n"**
```

I could see that libpq.so.5 is copied and available in /usr/pgsql-12/lib.

I have copied the library from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu to /usr/pgsql-12/lib and added /usr/pgsql-12/lib to PATH environment variable.

Comment: `PATH` is just for executables, not libraries. You probably want to read up on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. In general, trying to copy executables and their libraries around can be tricky - that's why there are packaging systems.